# Google Drive and Google Sites: Create Sub-page when new Google Drive folder is added

Tags: scripting, google-drive-api, google-sites, google-drive-realtime-api

I have organized my Google Drive all within a Google Site. Within Google Drive, each client has their own folder and on Google Sites I have a sub-page embedded with their associated Google Drive folder.

Now, when my team creates a new folder for a new client - I want my Google Sites page to recognize that new folder has been added, create a new sub-page, and embed that Google Drive folder so if any documents or changes are added it automatically updates on Google Drive.

Can I write a script for this? Or where could I learn how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> "Can I write a script for this?"

Possibly, AppScripts have been enabled to [work with Google Sites](http://regulargeek.com/2010/10/26/google-sites-automation-with-apps-script/) since 2010.

> "Where could I learn how to do this?"

Example of creating site/sub-page indicated in this [Appscript Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#copysitedomain-name-title-summary-site)

```
var site = SitesApp.createSite("example.com",
                                "homepage",
                                "My Home Page",
                                "This is a new site I created!");
```

Embedding Drive Folders using Appscript is possible using `DocsList.getFolderById('PASTE_FOLDER_ID_HERE').getFiles();`

Full tutorial is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites#prerequisites).

It would actually help if you knew some basics first. [This AppScript Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) could provide you with grounds to start with.